# Opencart targeting specific product_id

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to display the price of particular product (with the ID 51) on the home page. It is not a featured product, but something else entirely so I can't use the featured module.

I know the product ID is 51, so have tried to use the following:

```
<?php if (!$product[$product_id[51]]['special']) { ?>
    <?php echo $product[$product_id[51]]['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product_id[51]['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product_id[51]['special']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

but this only returns "undefined variable product_id". How do I display the price of this particular product?

MTIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the product in full using

```
$product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct(51);
```

Don't forget when using currency values you should format them appropriately using

```
$this->currency->format()
```

To get an idea of what code you need to be using, take a look inside the `catalog/controller/product/product.php` for the `special` and `price` coding

Comment: Thanks for this. Better method and good tips rather than create additional functions and mySQL database calls.